# Filtering on foreign key in django

Tags: python, django

In django, why does it not allow:

```
ItemInstance.objects.filter(provider_id__icontains='sting'))
```

But it does allow:

```
ItemInstance.objects.filter(provider__name__icontains='sting'))
```

`provider_id` and `provider__name` would give the same value, as the foreign key is to the `name` field. Why doesn't it allow the first method of referencing it?

Comment: Both should work.  What do your models look like?

Comment: Could you provide the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're using a natural key as the primary key: you've got `primary=True` on the name field? If so use this:

```
ItemInstance.objects.filter(provider_pk__icontains='sting'))
```

`id` field is only present if you don't specify your primary key. Django accommodates this my providing `pk`, which is a proxy for whatever field is your primary key